# Eclipse slow on headless build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-composer

I have a series of projects that I regularly build both through the IDE and through the headless build application.

I have noticed that whenever I use the headless build, the build takes much longer to execute, but from the logs the time needed to actually build is comparable in both the situation.

Example: I have projectA in workspaceA.

If I open the workspace in the IDE and build it, it takes 8 seconds to do a clean full build.

If I invoke the headless build from the command line like this:

```
path\to\eclipse\eclipsec.exe -noSplash --launcher.suppressErrors 
-data path\to\workspaceA -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
-build projectA/configuration -clean
```

The process takes like 40 seconds to finish, but the logs tells me that the build still finished in like 8.

Just to clarify, I am not using a vanilla version of eclipse, but Code Composer Studio v7.2.0.201705101800, with this version of eclipse packages installed:

- org.eclipse.platform version: 4.6.0.v20160606-1342
- org.eclipse.cdt version: 9.0.0.201606062011

Why this slowness? Is there a way to make it build in less time?